# Style a Button to an ActionBar item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-button

What style should I use to make a `Button` look like an item in the `ActionBar`? Thank you.

Comment: What you have try ? Do some google before ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used something like this:

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="actionbar_button" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu_bottom_button_selector</item>
    </style>
```

button_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@color/accent2" android:state_focused="true"/>          
    <item android:drawable="@color/accent2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_bottom_button_off" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

menu_bottom_button_off.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="@color/button_background"/>

</shape>
```

colors.xml:

```
<color name="accent2">#33b5e5</color>
<color name="button_background">@android:color/transparent</color>
```